# Raphael.js convert text to path

Tags: svg, raphael

I've setup a drawing utility with Raphael.js. The user can draw shapes, paths and enter text. Once a user adds text -> Paper.text() to the svg the svg goes into a selectable state. Meaning, if I add text and switch to the pen tool, moving the pen around the svg will cause adjacent dom elements to go into their ::selection state.

So I'd like to convert the text to a path to prevent this from happening. I don't see anything like this in the documentation.

Comment: please provide a js fiddle of your problem

Answer (score 4):

if you use print() instead of text() for text printing, then the text will be a raphael path object. (print() use a cufon javascript font that renders to a raphael path).

Answer (score 1):

Try tweaking the `pointer-events` property on the text elements with `.attr()`. `none` might fit your needs. There are some good [background info links on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events).

```
.attr({pointer-events: none})
```