# Displaying projection-transformed text on a canvas-based D3 globe

Tags: canvas, d3.js, map-projections

I'm using D3's [orthographic projection](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3757125) to build a [rotating globe](http://planetaryjs.com/examples/rotating.html) that gets drawn to a canvas. I'm adding shapes to the globe using `d3.geo.*`, particuarlly [`geo.circle`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#circle).

I would also like to display text on the globe (also via canvas), with the caveat that the text should exist *on* the globe, with proper transformation/curvature and clipping, like all the other GeoJSON/TopoJSON features that are rendered. However, [only shapes created via `d3.geo.path`](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/d3-js/131p4pq591/plotting-and-clipping-objects-on-the-globe#20130122wo7byxift7akqblikkgztjsoj4) can be drawn this way.

Is there a way to take some text (and a point, or perhaps a bounding box) and transform it via `d3.geo.path` so that it can be drawn correctly on the globe? Here is a photoshopped (poorly—the shapes aren't quite right) example of the sort of effect I'm after:

[image: Example]

Comment: Related: [converting SVG text to a path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594555/d3js-how-to-convert-svg-text-to-path). A path could be transformed the same way you've transformed the continents there.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to get the font as raw vectors and then create the text as a set of points to pass to d3.js for it to project it onto the map as it has done with the country outlines. The canvas is very limited in the transformations it can apply to elements like text. Orthographic projection is way outside its capabilities.

Thus you will have to get a font in vector format. The simplest way is to use photoshop, illustrator, inkscape, or any package that can vectorise a font for you and then write the function to create the text as a path from that vector font. I had a look through d3.js API documentation and there does not seem to be anything there to help with fonts.