# Any other ways to obtain the values of svg's bounding-rect

Tags: javascript, svg, jsdom

I have SVG elements that must be processed inside a JSDOM and need to obtain their getBBox() value.

while using getBBox() , as there is not painting performed inside a JSDOM the values are not obtained.

As I have many svgs in files and am in need of a method that finds the x, y , min ,max coordinates as like getBBox() and return those values. I have also tried methods like getBoundingClientRect()

https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2647
If getBBox() can't be used inside a JSDOM , is there any alternative approach for the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't replicate `getBBox()` in a headless environment without emulating a full fledged CSS and SVG rendering engine.

### Calculate BBox from x/y extremes

Provided, your svgs only contain geometry elements you can actually calculate
a bounding box from the element's [extreme x/y coordinates.](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#BoundingBoxes)

[image: from w3c §8.10. Bounding boxes]
*Illustration from w3c §8.10. Bounding boxes*

The geometry  element class includes:
`<path>`, `<polygon>`, `<polyline>`, `<circle>`, `<ellipse>`, `<rect>`, `<line>` elements.

Obviously, things get a bit more complicated with `<path>` elements as we first need to parse and normalize the path data to computable data objects.
For instance we need to convert relative commands to absolute. Besides, we need all segments to use longhand commands (e.g. `t`=>`Q`, `s`=>`C`, `h`/`v`=> `L`). See also ["Get bounding box of SVG path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315800/get-bounding-box-of-svg-path).

```js
function getBBoxFromEl(el) {
  let geoEls = ['path', 'line', 'polyline', 'polygon', 'circle', 'ellipse', 'rect'];

  let xMin = Infinity
  let xMax = -Infinity
  let yMin = Infinity
  let yMax = -Infinity
  let geometryEls

  //single element
  if (geoEls.includes(el.nodeName)) {
    geometryEls = [el]
  } else {
    geometryEls = el.querySelectorAll(`${geoEls.join(', ')}`)
  }

  geometryEls.forEach(geoEl => {
    let pathData = getPathDataFromEl(geoEl, {
      toAbsolute: true,
      toLonghands: true
    })
    let {
      x,
      y,
      width,
      height
    } = getPathDataBBox(pathData)

    if (x < xMin) {
      xMin = x
    }
    if (y < yMin) {
      yMin = y
    }

    if (x + width > xMax) {
      xMax = x + width
    }
    if (y + height > yMax) {
      yMax = y + height
    }
  })
  let bbN = {
    x: xMin,
    y: yMin,
    width: xMax - xMin,
    height: yMax - yMin
  }
  return bbN

}

function getBBoxFromD(d) {
  // normalize to absolute coordinates and longhand commands
  let pathData = parsePathDataNormalized(d);
  let bb = getPathDataBBox(pathData);
  console.log('bbox');
  return bb;
}

function getPathDataBBox(pathData) {

  // save extreme values
  let xMin = Infinity;
  let xMax = -Infinity;
  let yMin = Infinity;
  let yMax = -Infinity;

  const setXYmaxMin = (pt) => {
    if (pt.x < xMin) {
      xMin = pt.x
    }
    if (pt.x > xMax) {
      xMax = pt.x
    }
    if (pt.y < yMin) {
      yMin = pt.y
    }
    if (pt.y > yMax) {
      yMax = pt.y
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < pathData.length; i++) {
    let com = pathData[i]
    let {
      type,
      values
    } = com;
    let valuesL = values.length;
    let comPrev = pathData[i - 1] ? pathData[i - 1] : pathData[i];
    let valuesPrev = comPrev.values;
    let valuesPrevL = valuesPrev.length;

    if (valuesL) {
      let p0 = {
        x: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
        y: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
      };
      let p = {
        x: values[valuesL - 2],
        y: values[valuesL - 1]
      };
      // add final on path point
      setXYmaxMin(p)

      if (type === 'C' || type === 'Q') {
        let cp1 = {
          x: values[0],
          y: values[1]
        };
        let cp2 = type === 'C' ? {
          x: values[2],
          y: values[3]
        } : cp1;
        let pts = type === 'C' ? [p0, cp1, cp2, p] : [p0, cp1, p];

        let bezierExtremesT = getBezierExtremeT(pts)
        bezierExtremesT.forEach(t => {
          let pt = getPointAtBezierT(pts, t);
          setXYmaxMin(pt)
        })
      } else if (type === 'A') {
        let arcExtremes = getArcExtemes(p0, values)
        arcExtremes.forEach(pt => {
          setXYmaxMin(pt)
        })
      }
    }
  }

  let bbox = {
    x: xMin,
    y: yMin,
    width: xMax - xMin,
    height: yMax - yMin
  }
  return bbox
}


/**
 * based on Nikos M.'s answer
 * how-do-you-calculate-the-axis-aligned-bounding-box-of-an-ellipse
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87734/#75031511
 * See also: https://github.com/foo123/Geometrize
 */
function getArcExtemes(p0, values) {
  // compute point on ellipse from angle around ellipse (theta)
  const arc = (theta, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha) => {
    // alpha is angle of rotation of ellipse in radians
    var cos = Math.cos(alpha),
      sin = Math.sin(alpha),
      x = rx * Math.cos(theta),
      y = ry * Math.sin(theta);

    return {
      x: cx + cos * x - sin * y,
      y: cy + sin * x + cos * y
    };
  }

  //parametrize arcto data
  let arcData = svgArcToCenterParam(p0.x, p0.y, values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5], values[6]);
  let {
    rx,
    ry,
    pt,
    endAngle,
    deltaAngle
  } = arcData;

  // arc rotation
  let deg = values[2];
  let p = {
    x: values[5],
    y: values[6]
  }

  // circle/elipse center coordinates
  let [cx, cy] = [pt.x, pt.y];

  // collect extreme points – add end point
  let extremes = [p]

  // rotation to radians
  let alpha = deg * Math.PI / 180;
  let tan = Math.tan(alpha),
    p1, p2, p3, p4, theta;

  /**
   * find min/max from zeroes of directional derivative along x and y
   * along x axis
   */
  theta = Math.atan2(-ry * tan, rx);

  let angle1 = theta;
  let angle2 = theta + Math.PI;
  let angle3 = Math.atan2(ry, rx * tan);
  let angle4 = angle3 + Math.PI;

  // inner bounding box
  let xArr = [p0.x, p.x]
  let yArr = [p0.y, p.y]
  let xMin = Math.min(...xArr)
  let xMax = Math.max(...xArr)
  let yMin = Math.min(...yArr)
  let yMax = Math.max(...yArr)

  // on path point close after start
  let angleAfterStart = endAngle - deltaAngle * 0.001
  let pP2 = arc(angleAfterStart, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);

  // on path point close before end
  let angleBeforeEnd = endAngle - deltaAngle * 0.999
  let pP3 = arc(angleBeforeEnd, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);


  /**
   * expected extremes
   * if leaving inner bounding box
   * (between segment start and end point)
   * otherwise exclude elliptic extreme points
   */

  // right
  if (pP2.x > xMax || pP3.x > xMax) {
    // get point for this theta
    p1 = arc(angle1, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);
    extremes.push(p1)
  }

  // left
  if (pP2.x < xMin || pP3.x < xMin) {
    // get anti-symmetric point
    p2 = arc(angle2, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);
    extremes.push(p2)
  }

  // top
  if (pP2.y < yMin || pP3.y < yMin) {
    // get anti-symmetric point
    p4 = arc(angle4, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);
    extremes.push(p4)
  }

  // bottom
  if (pP2.y > yMax || pP3.y > yMax) {
    // get point for this theta
    p3 = arc(angle3, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);
    extremes.push(p3)
  }

  return extremes;
}


/**
 * based on @cuixiping;
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017100/calculate-center-of-svg-arc/12329083#12329083
 */
function svgArcToCenterParam(x1, y1, rx, ry, degree, fA, fS, x2, y2) {
  const radian = (ux, uy, vx, vy) => {
    let dot = ux * vx + uy * vy;
    let mod = Math.sqrt((ux * ux + uy * uy) * (vx * vx + vy * vy));
    let rad = Math.acos(dot / mod);
    if (ux * vy - uy * vx < 0) {
      rad = -rad;
    }
    return rad;
  };
  // degree to radian
  let phi = (degree * Math.PI) / 180;
  let cx, cy, startAngle, deltaAngle, endAngle;
  let PI = Math.PI;
  let PIx2 = PI * 2;
  if (rx < 0) {
    rx = -rx;
  }
  if (ry < 0) {
    ry = -ry;
  }
  if (rx == 0 || ry == 0) {
    // invalid arguments
    throw Error("rx and ry can not be 0");
  }
  let s_phi = Math.sin(phi);
  let c_phi = Math.cos(phi);
  let hd_x = (x1 - x2) / 2; // half diff of x
  let hd_y = (y1 - y2) / 2; // half diff of y
  let hs_x = (x1 + x2) / 2; // half sum of x
  let hs_y = (y1 + y2) / 2; // half sum of y

  let x1_ = c_phi * hd_x + s_phi * hd_y;
  let y1_ = c_phi * hd_y - s_phi * hd_x;

  //   Step 3: Ensure radii are large enough
  let lambda = (x1_ * x1_) / (rx * rx) + (y1_ * y1_) / (ry * ry);
  if (lambda > 1) {
    rx = rx * Math.sqrt(lambda);
    ry = ry * Math.sqrt(lambda);
  }
  let rxry = rx * ry;
  let rxy1_ = rx * y1_;
  let ryx1_ = ry * x1_;
  let sum_of_sq = rxy1_ * rxy1_ + ryx1_ * ryx1_; // sum of square
  if (!sum_of_sq) {
    throw Error("start point can not be same as end point");
  }
  let coe = Math.sqrt(Math.abs((rxry * rxry - sum_of_sq) / sum_of_sq));
  if (fA == fS) {
    coe = -coe;
  }
  let cx_ = (coe * rxy1_) / ry;
  let cy_ = (-coe * ryx1_) / rx;

  cx = c_phi * cx_ - s_phi * cy_ + hs_x;
  cy = s_phi * cx_ + c_phi * cy_ + hs_y;
  let xcr1 = (x1_ - cx_) / rx;
  let xcr2 = (x1_ + cx_) / rx;
  let ycr1 = (y1_ - cy_) / ry;
  let ycr2 = (y1_ + cy_) / ry;

  startAngle = radian(1, 0, xcr1, ycr1);
  deltaAngle = radian(xcr1, ycr1, -xcr2, -ycr2);
  if (deltaAngle > PIx2) {
    deltaAngle -= PIx2;
  } else if (deltaAngle < 0) {
    deltaAngle += PIx2;
  }
  if (fS == false || fS == 0) {
    deltaAngle -= PIx2;
  }
  endAngle = startAngle + deltaAngle;
  if (endAngle > PIx2) {
    endAngle -= PIx2;
  } else if (endAngle < 0) {
    endAngle += PIx2;
  }
  let toDegFactor = 180 / PI;
  let outputObj = {
    pt: {
      x: cx,
      y: cy
    },
    rx: rx,
    ry: ry,
    startAngle_deg: startAngle * toDegFactor,
    startAngle: startAngle,
    deltaAngle_deg: deltaAngle * toDegFactor,
    deltaAngle: deltaAngle,
    endAngle_deg: endAngle * toDegFactor,
    endAngle: endAngle,
    clockwise: fS == true || fS == 1
  };
  return outputObj;
}



// wrapper functions for quadratic or cubic bezier point calculation
function getPointAtBezierT(pts, t) {
  let pt = pts.length === 4 ? getPointAtCubicSegmentT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], pts[3], t) : getPointAtQuadraticSegmentT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], t)
  return pt
}

function getBezierExtremeT(pts) {
  let tArr = pts.length === 4 ? cubicBezierExtremeT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], pts[3]) : quadraticBezierExtremeT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2]);
  return tArr;
}


function cubicBezierExtremeT(p0, cp1, cp2, p) {
  let [x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3] = [p0.x, p0.y, cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, p.x, p.y];

  /**
   * if control points are within 
   * bounding box of start and end point 
   * we cant't have extremes
   */
  let top = Math.min(p0.y, p.y)
  let left = Math.min(p0.x, p.x)
  let right = Math.max(p0.x, p.x)
  let bottom = Math.max(p0.y, p.y)

  if (
    cp1.y >= top && cp1.y <= bottom &&
    cp2.y >= top && cp2.y <= bottom &&
    cp1.x >= left && cp1.x <= right &&
    cp2.x >= left && cp2.x <= right
  ) {
    return []
  }

  var tArr = [],
    a, b, c, t, t1, t2, b2ac, sqrt_b2ac;
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      b = 6 * x0 - 12 * x1 + 6 * x2;
      a = -3 * x0 + 9 * x1 - 9 * x2 + 3 * x3;
      c = 3 * x1 - 3 * x0;
    } else {
      b = 6 * y0 - 12 * y1 + 6 * y2;
      a = -3 * y0 + 9 * y1 - 9 * y2 + 3 * y3;
      c = 3 * y1 - 3 * y0;
    }
    if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-12) {
      if (Math.abs(b) < 1e-12) {
        continue;
      }
      t = -c / b;
      if (0 < t && t < 1) {
        tArr.push(t);
      }
      continue;
    }
    b2ac = b * b - 4 * c * a;
    if (b2ac < 0) {
      if (Math.abs(b2ac) < 1e-12) {
        t = -b / (2 * a);
        if (0 < t && t < 1) {
          tArr.push(t);
        }
      }
      continue;
    }
    sqrt_b2ac = Math.sqrt(b2ac);
    t1 = (-b + sqrt_b2ac) / (2 * a);
    if (0 < t1 && t1 < 1) {
      tArr.push(t1);
    }
    t2 = (-b - sqrt_b2ac) / (2 * a);
    if (0 < t2 && t2 < 1) {
      tArr.push(t2);
    }
  }

  var j = tArr.length;
  while (j--) {
    t = tArr[j];
  }
  return tArr;

}

//For quadratic bezier.
function quadraticBezierExtremeT(p0, cp1, p) {
  /**
   * if control points are within 
   * bounding box of start and end point 
   * we cant't have extremes
   */
  let top = Math.min(p0.y, p.y)
  let left = Math.min(p0.x, p.x)
  let right = Math.max(p0.x, p.x)
  let bottom = Math.max(p0.y, p.y)

  if (
    cp1.y >= top && cp1.y <= bottom &&
    cp1.x >= left && cp1.x <= right
  ) {
    return []
  }


  let [x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2] = [p0.x, p0.y, cp1.x, cp1.y, p.x, p.y];
  let extemeT = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    a = i == 0 ? x0 - 2 * x1 + x2 : y0 - 2 * y1 + y2;
    b = i == 0 ? -2 * x0 + 2 * x1 : -2 * y0 + 2 * y1;
    c = i == 0 ? x0 : y0;
    if (Math.abs(a) > 1e-12) {
      t = -b / (2 * a);
      if (t > 0 && t < 1) {
        extemeT.push(t);
      }
    }
  }
  return extemeT
}


// retrieve pathdata from svg geometry elements
function getPathDataFromEl(el) {
  let pathData = [];
  let type = el.nodeName;
  let atts, attNames, d, x, y, width, height, r, rx, ry, cx, cy, x1, x2, y1, y2;

  // convert relative or absolute units 
  svgElUnitsToPixel(el)

  const getAtts = (attNames) => {
    atts = {}
    attNames.forEach(att => {
      atts[att] = +el.getAttribute(att)
    })
    return atts
  }

  switch (type) {
    case 'path':
      d = el.getAttribute("d");
      pathData = parsePathDataNormalized(d);
      break;

    case 'rect':
      attNames = ['x', 'y', 'width', 'height', 'rx', 'ry'];
      ({
        x,
        y,
        width,
        height,
        rx,
        ry
      } = getAtts(attNames));


      if (!rx && !ry) {
        pathData = [{
            type: "M",
            values: [x, y]
          },
          {
            type: "H",
            values: [x + width]
          },
          {
            type: "V",
            values: [y + height]
          },
          {
            type: "H",
            values: [x]
          },
          {
            type: "Z",
            values: []
          }
        ];
      } else {

        if (rx > width / 2) {
          rx = width / 2;
        }
        if (ry > height / 2) {
          ry = height / 2;
        }

        pathData = [{
            type: "M",
            values: [x + rx, y]
          },
          {
            type: "H",
            values: [x + width - rx]
          },
          {
            type: "A",
            values: [rx, ry, 0, 0, 1, x + width, y + ry]
          },
          {
            type: "V",
            values: [y + height - ry]
          },
          {
            type: "A",
            values: [rx, ry, 0, 0, 1, x + width - rx, y + height]
          },
          {
            type: "H",
            values: [x + rx]
          },
          {
            type: "A",
            values: [rx, ry, 0, 0, 1, x, y + height - ry]
          },
          {
            type: "V",
            values: [y + ry]
          },
          {
            type: "A",
            values: [rx, ry, 0, 0, 1, x + rx, y]
          },
          {
            type: "Z",
            values: []
          }
        ];
      }
      break;

    case 'circle':
    case 'ellipse':

      attNames = ['cx', 'cy', 'rx', 'ry', 'r'];
      ({
        cx,
        cy,
        r,
        rx,
        ry
      } = getAtts(attNames));

      if (type === 'circle') {
        r = r;
        rx = r
        ry = r
      } else {
        rx = rx ? rx : r;
        ry = ry ? ry : r;
      }

      pathData = [{
          type: "M",
          values: [cx + rx, cy]
        },
        {
          type: "A",
          values: [rx, ry, 0, 1, 1, cx - rx, cy]
        },
        {
          type: "A",
          values: [rx, ry, 0, 1, 1, cx + rx, cy]
        },
      ];

      break;
    case 'line':
      attNames = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'];
      ({
        x1,
        y1,
        x2,
        y2
      } = getAtts(attNames));
      pathData = [{
          type: "M",
          values: [x1, y1]
        },
        {
          type: "L",
          values: [x2, y2]
        }
      ];
      break;
    case 'polygon':
    case 'polyline':

      let points = el.getAttribute('points').replaceAll(',', ' ').split(' ').filter(Boolean)

      for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2) {
        pathData.push({
          type: (i === 0 ? "M" : "L"),
          values: [+points[i], +points[i + 1]]
        });
      }
      if (type === 'polygon') {
        pathData.push({
          type: "Z",
          values: []
        });
      }
      break;
  }

  return pathData;
};

/**
 * calculate single points on segments
 */
function getPointAtCubicSegmentT(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  return {
    x: t1 ** 3 * p0.x +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.x +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.x +
      t ** 3 * p.x,
    y: t1 ** 3 * p0.y +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.y +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.y +
      t ** 3 * p.y
  };
}

function getPointAtQuadraticSegmentT(p0, cp1, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  return {
    x: t1 * t1 * p0.x + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.x + t ** 2 * p.x,
    y: t1 * t1 * p0.y + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.y + t ** 2 * p.y
  };
}

function svgElUnitsToPixel(el, decimals = 5) {
  //console.log(this);
  const svg = el.nodeName !== "svg" ? el.closest("svg") : el;

  // convert real life units to pixels
  const translateUnitToPixel = (value) => {

    if (value === null) {
      return 0
    }
    //default dpi = 96
    let dpi = 96;
    let unit = value.match(/([a-z]+)/gi);
    unit = unit ? unit[0] : "";
    let val = parseFloat(value);
    let rat;

    // no unit - already pixes/user unit
    if (!unit) {
      return val;
    }

    switch (unit) {
      case "in":
        rat = dpi;
        break;
      case "pt":
        rat = (1 / 72) * 96;
        break;
      case "cm":
        rat = (1 / 2.54) * 96;
        break;
      case "mm":
        rat = ((1 / 2.54) * 96) / 10;
        break;
        // just a default approximation
      case "em":
        rat = 16;
        break;
      default:
        rat = 1;
    }
    let valuePx = val * rat;
    return +valuePx.toFixed(decimals);
  };

  // svg width and height attributes
  let width = svg.getAttribute("width");
  width = width ? translateUnitToPixel(width) : 300;
  let height = svg.getAttribute("height");
  height = width ? translateUnitToPixel(height) : 150;

  //prefer viewBox values
  let vB = svg.getAttribute("viewBox");
  vB = vB ?
    vB
    .replace(/,/g, " ")
    .split(" ")
    .filter(Boolean)
    .map((val) => {
      return +val;
    }) : [];

  let w = vB.length ? vB[2] : width;
  let h = vB.length ? vB[3] : height;
  let scaleX = 0.01 * w;
  let scaleY = 0.01 * h;
  let scalRoot = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(scaleX, 2) + Math.pow(scaleY, 2)) / 2);
  let attsH = ["x", "width", "x1", "x2", "rx", "cx", "r"];
  let attsV = ["y", "height", "y1", "y2", "ry", "cy"];


  let atts = el.getAttributeNames();
  atts.forEach((att) => {
    let val = el.getAttribute(att);
    let valAbs = val;
    if (attsH.includes(att) || attsV.includes(att)) {
      let scale = attsH.includes(att) ? scaleX : scaleY;
      scale = att === "r" && w != h ? scalRoot : scale;
      let unit = val.match(/([a-z|%]+)/gi);
      unit = unit ? unit[0] : "";
      if (val.includes("%")) {
        valAbs = parseFloat(val) * scale;
      }
      //absolute units
      else {
        valAbs = translateUnitToPixel(val);
      }
      el.setAttribute(att, +valAbs);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grd {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2em;
  height: 95vh;
}

.col {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.col * {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  min-height: 10em;
  height: 50%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

input[type="range"] {
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}

#valLength {
  display: block;
}

code {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grd">
  <div class="col">
    <h3>Input you pathdata</h3>
    <p>Svg gets cropped to the bounding box</p>
    <h3>Bounding box (calculated/native)</h3>
    <pre><code id="bbOut"></code></pre>
    <textarea id="svgInput">
                <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                    <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="
M3 7 13 7m-10 10 10 0V27H23v10h10C33 43 38 47 43 47c0 5 5 10 10 10S63 67 63 67s-10 10 10 10Q50 50 73 57q20-5 0-10T70 40t0-15A5 10 45 1040 20a5 5 20 01-10-10Z" />
                    <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="
                      M20 90a 5 10 66  1 0 10 -8" />
                    <ellipse id="ellipse" fill="none" stroke="#E3000F" cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="90" ry="30" />
                </svg>
          </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="preview">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- parse pathdata -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg-parse-path-normalized@latest/js/pathDataParseNormalized.js"></script>


<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    updateSVG();
  });
  svgInput.addEventListener('input', e => {
    updateSVG();
  })


  function updateSVG() {
    // reset preview
    preview.innerHTML = ''
    let ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
    let svgPreview
    let input = svgInput.value;

    //is svg
    if (input.includes('<svg')) {
      svgPreview = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, 'text/html').querySelector('svg')
    }
    // is single path d string
    else {
      svgPreview = document.createElementNS(ns, 'svg')
      path = document.createElementNS(ns, 'path')
      d = svgInput.value
      path.setAttribute('d', d)
      svgPreview.append(path)
    }


    preview.append(svgPreview)

    // adjust viewBox
    let bb = getBBoxFromEl(svgPreview)
    let bbString = [bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height].join(' ')

    //native
    let bbN = svgPreview.getBBox()
    let bbNString = [bbN.x, bbN.y, bbN.width, bbN.height].join(' ')

    bbOut.textContent = `${bbString} \n${bbNString} // native`

    svgPreview.setAttribute('viewBox', bbString)
    let {
      x,
      y,
      width,
      height
    } = bb;
  }
</script>
```

#### getBBox in node.js/jsDom

You'll find quite a few libraries on npm. See search result for ["svg bounding box"](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=svg%20bounding%20box).

The above example is based on my own experimental [library/repository](https://github.com/herrstrietzel/svg-pathdata-getbbox) you can install via npm like so

```
npm install svg-pathdata-getbbox
```

Combined with jsDom you can get a bbox like so

```JS
var pathDataBB = require("svg-pathdata-getbbox");
var { getBBoxFromEl, getBBoxFromD, getPathDataBBox, } = pathDataBB;
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

let svgMarkup = `<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M3 7 13 7m-10 10 10 0V27H23v10h10C33 43 38 47 43 47c0 5 5 10 10 10S63 67 63 67s-10 10 10 10Q50 50 73 57q20-5 0-10T70 40t0-15A5 10 45 1040 20a5 5 20 01-10-10Z"/>
</svg>`;

const dom = new JSDOM(svgMarkup);
let svg = dom.window.document.querySelector('svg')

let bb = getBBoxFromEl(svg)
console.log(bb);
```

### Limitations/not supported

#### 1.`<text>` elements

Calculating a bbox for a text element would require to retrieve and parse the used font family (already not trivial as this font needs to be available for loading ... or you need a routine to auto detect paths, external URLS etc.).

Then you would need to calculate the total boundaries e.g. by converting text to path and computing all characters bboxes. See related SO post ["D3js : How to convert svg text to path?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594555/d3js-how-to-convert-svg-text-to-path)

Quite likely you won't be able to approximate all kind of text objects (text paths, texts using variable or color fonts)

#### 2. elements styled by CSS

As we can also define a lot of "presentation attributes" via CSS e.g `d`(path data) we would ultimately need a full fledged CSS parser to calculate the bounding box coming from CSS rules. Not aware of a node library that is capable of this :(

#### 3. Transformed elements

Transformations are ignored. You may convert all [transformations to hardcoded coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149301/baking-transforms-into-svg-path-element-commands).